# Jackson TypeInfo

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Такой вопрос: 
Resttemplate возвращает responseEntity , которая автоматически десериализуется ObjectMappe (Jackson), в json который приходит есть поля @class: "Object" , стоит следующая задача нужна заменить название класса на своё , каким образом это можно сделать ? 
Вроде бы есть DefaultTypeResolverBuilder , но он вроде как наоборот собирает json (сериализует)
Возможно есть какой-то препроцессор , чтобы перед десериализацией обработать json как string и просто заменить что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не повторятся, вот вам статейка [Inheritance with Jackson | Beeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

Если коротко можно делать так:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type") // имя поля, в которое будет записан тип
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"),  // синонимы для типов
  @Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck") 
})
public abstract class Vehicle {
    // fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
```

В итоге получим это:

```
{
    "vehicles": 
    [
        {
            "type": "car",
            "make": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "model": "S500",
            "seatingCapacity": 5,
            "topSpeed": 250.0
        },

        {
            "type": "truck",
            "make": "Isuzu",
            "model": "NQR",
            "payloadCapacity": 7500.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ну и зачем мне это? Я же спрашиваю как подменять приходящий json , а так вы просто отправите json с типом который указали

Comment: "а так вы просто отправите json с типом который указали" - а это и не есть замена? Или вы думаете, что при десереализации эти типы использоваться не будут?

Comment: Вы еще можете посмотреть http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest - обернуть Jackson message converter в свой, который будет уже проводить нужные замены. Это и будет ваш "препроцессор, чтобы обработать как string". Но честно я не знаю зачем вам это, если typeinfo и так справится с этой задачей намного лучше. Либо я абсолютно не понял, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: В том то и проблема что отправляю json не я , а другой микросервис , но при этом выставляет неправильный пакет , когда я получаю его нужно подменить

Comment: Так и пропишите правильные пакеты.в @TypeInfo. Например. Ваш класс `correct.pack.MyClass`, пишем в TypeInfo `name = incorrect.pack.MyClass`. А вообще по хорошему будет или поправить тот сервис, что шлет вам данные или переместить классы в правильный пакет. Иначе любое решение будет костылем.